# Seeding with Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

What i'm trying to accomplish is that I am trying to seed my database through the use of migrations and getting an error b/c one of the tables/classes has a foreign key and when I try seed data, I keep getting an error. This is the first time doing this so any help would be very much appreciated.

Here are my classes:

```
 public class SelectOption
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public SelectOptionType OptionTypeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "UserName length exceeded.")]
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
}

 public class SelectOptionType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name length exceeded.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my seed method:

```
 protected override void Seed(TestApp.Infrastructure.Context context)
    {

        context.SelectOptionTypes.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Name,
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Cleaning/Housekeeping"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Doors"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Electrical"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Fire and Safety"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Furniture"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "General Repairs"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Heating/Air Conditioning"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Key/Card Access"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Light Bulbs/Lighting"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Plumbering"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "University Applicances"},
            new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Pest Control"}
            );

        context.SelectOptions.AddOrUpdate(d => d.OptionTypeId,
            new SelectOption() { OptionTypeId = new SelectOptionType() { Name = "Cleaning/Housekeeping" }, OptionValue = "Carpet is wet" }
            );




    }
```

The Error i am receiver in the package manager console:
Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestApplication.Model.SelectOptionType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you can't use something like a reference property as the first param to `AddOrUpdate`. It has to be passed a property that is scalar (string, int, etc.). If you had an actual id property to represent the relationship, such that `OptionTypeId` was of type `int` and then your reference property was something like `OptionType` instead, then you could use `OptionTypeId` as the property for the first parameter.